# What numerical methods could I use for this argmin problem?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization, hypergeometric-function

I wish to solve the following using Numerical Methods:
$$
\bar{m} = \underset{m \geq 0}{\text{argmin}} \left( \int_a^b \left( \frac{1}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^M \left(c_i^\alpha \cdot n^2 y^{-m-1} \cdot \int_0^1 \left( 1-x\right)^{n-1} \cdot x^m \cdot \left(1 - z \cdot x \right)^{n-1} dx\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{f(x)}} \right)^2 dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

I already know the following:

1. $c_i^\alpha$ for all $i$
2. M
3. n
4. y
5. z
6. f(x); note: f(x) is quite hideous, so I spared writing out the formula. it doesn't contain any of the parameters listed in (1 through 5).  It's just ugly.
7. and interval [a,b]

I will also point out that $\int_0^1 \left( 1-x\right)^{n-1} \cdot x^m \cdot \left(1 - z \cdot x \right)^{n-1} dx$ comes from the [Euler type Gaussian hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type)

What I have considered doing:

- Try using lagrange multiplier on this.  The trouble is is that I am overwhelmed by the math and am not sure how to use the lagrange multiplier on this problem.

any help pointing me into the right direction into solving this problem (via lagrange multiplier or something else) would be great.

-Jas

Comment: At very first, you should simplify your problem: Remove the outer square-root, evaluate the inner integral... Afterwards, you should compute the derivative of the function inside the $\argmin$. Then, check its sign at $0$ (negative => local minimizer) and the zeros of the derivative.

Comment: This is clearly a nonconvex problem. You may treat it as a black box: you need to minimize a function $F(m)$ over $m\geq 0$. Sequential convex programming may help, although there is no guarantee that it will (globally) converge even to a local minimum. You may try particle swarm methods.